# Preview form data before submission

Tags: jquery, django

Are there any tools for previewing a Django form as the user provides input?

I've checked around S/O and don't see anything other than using the built-in preview function after submission. That seems antiquated.

I know you can do it using Jquery for simple text fields (like this: http://volter9.github.io/Form-Preview/) but I'd like to do it with a wysiwyg editor like TinyMCE.

Any tips would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for. it allows you to type in the first input and preview content in the second form input.

I also added the ability to preview the tinymce inputted data in a div via div_result

```
<div>
<label>Input1. your tinymce form input</label>
 <input type="text" id="input1" value="">
</div>

</br>
<label>Input2</label>
<input type="text" id="input2" value="">

<div id='div_result'></div>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#input1").keyup(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
                $("#input2").val(value);
$("#div_result").html(value);
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @nancy-moree. Will give it a shot.